# Sheets: Need to count mismatched specific occurrences in two columns, and format for a two-series bar chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

Simple example: each column contains either blank cells or specific sizes of shoe.

| usable | damaged |
| --- | --- |
| 40 |  |
|  | 41 |
| 41 |  |
| 40 |  |
| 42 |  |
|  | 38 |

I can successfully get the count of each occurrence in two separate tables (placed adjacent below):

```
=QUERY(A1:B7,"select A, COUNT(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A) 'USABLE'",1)
```

```
=QUERY(A1:B7,"select B, COUNT(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B) 'DAMAGED'",1)
```

| usable | USABLE | damaged | DAMAGED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 2 | 38 | 1 |
| 41 | 1 | 41 | 1 |
| 42 | 1 |  |  |

I now want to create a two-series bar chart to visually compare the number of usable/damaged shoe sizes. Because I only have certain sizes in one of the two columns, the x-axis doesn't match and the graphed data is incorrect.

[Two-series bar chart w/ sidebar settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbsBt.png)

---

I tried counting both columns with the function below:

```
=QUERY(A1:B7,"SELECT A,B, COUNT(A),COUNT(B) GROUP BY A,B LABEL COUNT(A) 'Usable', COUNT(B) 'Damaged'", 1)
```

...which spits out:

| usable | damaged | Usable | Damaged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 38 | 0 | 1 |
|  | 41 | 0 | 1 |
| 40 |  | 2 | 0 |
| 41 |  | 1 | 0 |
| 42 |  | 1 | 0 |

This doesn't seem to be very conducive for graphing.

I cannot understand how to easily format the output to look like this (for ease of graphing):

| Shoe Size | USABLE | DAMAGED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 38 | 0 | 1 |
| 40 | 2 | 0 |
| 41 | 1 | 1 |
| 42 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you you have an option that finds the unique values, and then lists that size with both COUNTIF:

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:B,1)),LAMBDA(size,{size,COUNTIF(A:A,size),COUNTIF(B:B,size)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what table/data you're referencing? Your picture doesn't show everything.

Comment: I'm assuming the initial data range, but I'm getting the entire "SIZE" column populated with the error "Unknown range name: 'EACH'."

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. Change "each" with "size". I changed the name at the last moment and forgot to change that appearance

Comment: Thanks! Where can I add an ascending function to the size column?

Comment: Use SORT wrapping UNIQUE: `=BYROW(SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:B,1))),LAMBDA.....`

Comment: Or in fact, you could just wrap the entire formula in SORT

Comment: Ok but I still had to enter the other requirements for SORT (reference column 1 and true=ascending), which I figured out: `=BYROW(SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:B,1)),1,TRUE),LAMBDA(size,{size,COUNTIF(A2:A,size),COUNTIF(B2:B,size)}))`

Comment: Nope, if you put just SORT it assumes it's by the first column ascending. But yes, of course you can write it too! `=BYROW(SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:B,1))),LAMBDA(each,{each,COUNTIF(A:A,each),COUNTIF(B:B,each)}))` or `=SORT(BYROW(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:B,1)),LAMBDA(each,{each,COUNTIF(A:A,each),COUNTIF(B:B,each)})))`

Answer (score 0):

An "old-school" solution:

`=QUERY({query({query({A2:A7,C2:C7,A2:A7},"select Col1,Col2 , Count(Col1)where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label Count(Col1) ''");query({B2:B7,B2:B7,C2:C7},"select Col1,  Count(Col1),Col3 where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col3 label Count(Col1) ''")},"select Col1, Col3, Col2")},"SELECT Col1, Sum(Col2),Sum(Col3) group by Col1 label Col1 'Shoe Size', Sum(Col2) 'USABLE', Sum(Col3) 'DAMAGED'")`

---

**Logic**

The answer is based on two stacked nested queries

- #1 = Usable by Shoe size
- #2 = Damaged by Shoe size

These are used as the source range in a final query; values in Col2 ("Usable") and Col3 ("Damaged") are summed and the results are grouped by Col1 (Shoe Size)

---

**RESULTS**

[image: snapshot]